# Two table headers with multiple colspans

Tags: html

I'm trying to achieve a certain format for a table, but I'm failing to get the last part of it correct, also struggling to find answers for it online since I don't know exactly the keywords for this.

Here's what I have:

```html
<table border="2">

  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Title #1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Title #2</td>
  </tr>

  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 0</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 1</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 2</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Area 3</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 4</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 5</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

I need Areas 3 to 5 to go under Title 2, but am failing to achieve that result. Please and thank you.

Comment: You want 3 items to go in a space with a colspan of 2?

Comment: A better way of saying it might be I want 3 rows of 2 columns under both titles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```html
<table border="2">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Title #1</td>
    <td colspan="2">Title #2</td>
  </tr>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 0</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Area 3</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 1</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Area 4</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Area 2</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>Area 5</td>
      <td>0</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```